# Steam constantly timeouts

Tags: networking, windows-8, dns, http, steam

Surface Pro 3 i5 4GB RAM, Windows 8.1

I cannot update steam or any installed games. They all download very slowly (<10kb/s) and then fail and reset.

Attached is the log from the C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\logs\content_log.txt

```
[2015-06-22 22:58:14] Loaded 2 apps from install folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\appmanifest_*.acf".
[2015-06-22 22:58:32] Scheduler update appID 570: Priority Last, legacy=no, restore=""
[2015-06-22 22:58:38] AppID 570 state changed : Fully Installed,Update Optional,Update Running,
[2015-06-22 22:58:38] AppID 570 update changed : Running,
[2015-06-22 22:58:38] AppID 570 update changed : Running,Reconfiguring,
[2015-06-22 22:58:48] Got 20 download sources via "/serverlist/8/20/" from 173.245.218.194:80
[2015-06-22 22:58:48] Created download interface of type 'CDN' (2) to host cdn.akamai.cs.steampowered.com (cdn.akamai.cs.steampowered.com)
[2015-06-22 22:58:48] Created download interface of type 'CDN' (2) to host cdn.akamai.cs.steampowered.com (cdn.akamai.cs.steampowered.com)
[2015-06-22 22:58:48] Created download interface of type 'CDN' (2) to host cdn.highwinds.cs.steampowered.com (cdn.highwinds.cs.steampowered.com)
[2015-06-22 22:58:48] HTTP (CDN,11) - cdn.akamai.cs.steampowered.com (cdn.akamai.cs.steampowered.com): AuthenticateDepotID (373301) - Success!
[2015-06-22 22:58:48] HTTP (CDN,4) - cdn.highwinds.cs.steampowered.com (cdn.highwinds.cs.steampowered.com): AuthenticateDepotID (373303) - Success!
[2015-06-22 22:58:48] HTTP (CDN,11) - cdn.akamai.cs.steampowered.com (cdn.akamai.cs.steampowered.com): AuthenticateDepotID (381450) - Success!
[2015-06-22 22:59:21] HTTP (CDN,11) - cdn.akamai.cs.steampowered.com (cdn.akamai.cs.steampowered.com): Depot 373301 request for manifest 2842229011057406328 - timed out waiting for response
[2015-06-22 22:59:21] HTTP (CDN,11) - cdn.akamai.cs.steampowered.com (cdn.akamai.cs.steampowered.com): Closing connection
[2015-06-22 22:59:35] HTTP (CDN,11) - cdn.akamai.cs.steampowered.com (cdn.akamai.cs.steampowered.com): Depot 381450 request for manifest 3296450722116333543 - timed out waiting for response
[2015-06-22 22:59:35] HTTP (CDN,11) - cdn.akamai.cs.steampowered.com (cdn.akamai.cs.steampowered.com): Closing connection
[2015-06-22 22:59:50] HTTP (CDN,4) - cdn.highwinds.cs.steampowered.com (cdn.highwinds.cs.steampowered.com): Depot 373303 request for manifest 620912628214011567 - timed out waiting for response
[2015-06-22 22:59:50] HTTP (CDN,4) - cdn.highwinds.cs.steampowered.com (cdn.highwinds.cs.steampowered.com): Closing connection
[2015-06-22 23:00:48] AppID 570 update canceled : missing manifest 2842229011057406328 (Connection timeout)
[2015-06-22 23:00:48] AppID 570 update changed : Running,Reconfiguring,Stopping,
[2015-06-22 23:00:48] AppID 570 update changed : Running,Stopping,
[2015-06-22 23:00:48] AppID 570 update changed : None
[2015-06-22 23:00:48] AppID 570 state changed : Fully Installed,Update Optional, (Connection timeout)
[2015-06-22 23:00:48] AppID 570 scheduler finished : removed from schedule
```

I've tried `ping`-ing and `tracert`-ing various valvexxx.cs.steampowered.com servers and it appears that there doesn't seem to be any packet loss.

Stuff I've tried doing to fix it:

- Reset computer
- Switch off firewall
- Change DNS to GoogleDNS
- ipconfig /flushdns
- Turn off "automatically detect settings" in internet Options
- netsh winsock reset

I can install games on other networks, and installing/downloading games on a Macbook works. So it appears to be a problem with my computer only.

Comment: It seems like an issue with your ISP if I had to guess. I know we had issues where steam traffic was earmarked as peer to peer for some reason. Check to see if your ISP shapes traffic by using this tool - http://broadband.mpi-sws.org/transparency/bttest.php

Comment: Just try turning off your steam cloud from options/multiplayer/advanced no fancy playing around with client registry or anything like that.
Deleting the client registry file only gives you a temporary fix..
Turning off the sync with steam cloud may fix the problem straight away.

Comment: It does appear that bittorrent transfers are blocked on my ISP.

Answer (score 0):

It might be something trivial.

First I would like you to check if the download speed isn't limited:

http://lifehacker.com/steam-latest-beta-lets-you-limit-your-download-speed-479692897

---

Than, check the download speed of other programs as well.

If this doesn't help, I will update my answer with more solutions.

Comment: The download speed is set to no limit.

Chrome (Youtube), Spotify and Google Drive work fine.

Comment: Is the region also set right?

Comment: I've tried multiple regions and none have helped.

Comment: what kind of antivirus are You using? If You use one.

Comment: I don't use any antivirus.

Comment: Do You use a router? / Does your router support QoS?